# Configure Visual Studio to use more ram

Tags: visual-studio-2010, memory, ram

I read a blog post at one time on how to increase the amount of RAM that Visual Studio will use. I am getting a "Not enough memory free" error message when trying to copy a small line of text in the visual studio editor.

Does anybody know how or where I can configure this?

Comment: Jonathan Allen's answer is actually the correct one for the message you are seeing: in this case, VS really is *not* out of memory.   You are seeing this because of the editor's use of [MemoryFailPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint.aspx) and a behavior we weren't expecting, namely that MemoryFailPoint isn't very granular, and turns a request for "is there enough memory to copy this line" into a request about finding a much larger piece of contiguous memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to get that. I forget which of the many hotfixes got rid of it.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB2251084/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4544

Answer (score 7):

Here is a blog posts matching your description:

[http://mkwec.de/2010/01/08/make-visual-studio-use-more-than-2-gig-of-memory/](http://web.archive.org/web/20151221132808/http://mkwec.de/2010/01/08/make-visual-studio-use-more-than-2-gig-of-memory)

Comment: That was the post that I read before! Thanks! Couldn't find it for the love of god.

Comment: It shows the steps regarding Windows XP and Vista. Is there any other solution for Win 8?