# How to make Visual Studio 2010 use more than 600Mb of memory

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, memory

I am tired of how slow the VS2010 is. I know there are a lot of topics here about tuning the settings and I've read/applied them all with not much luck though. Namely the things I've already done:

- removed all the extensions
- never had a resharper
- tuned the settings to get maximum performance
- tried SSD and RAM disks

Nothing helped it is still unacceptably slow. I know what I am saying because with VS2008 I never had such problems.

Now, I am working on a quite big C# solution with about 20 projects in it. Visual Studio works quite fast when just opened, but as time goes it starts lagging and eventually gets so slow that I have to restart it. The resource monitor shows that the amount of memory consumed by it is about 200 MB in the beginning and goes up to ~600 MB and then doesn't go any higher. I have 8 GB of total RAM on a x64 laptop with about 4GB that are always free. I find it weird how little memory the VS uses and from what my common sense tells me the more memory the faster the app should work. So I believe my question is how to make the VS use more of the available memory.

PS
I tried a recipe from [Configure Visual Studio to use more ram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845188/configure-visual-studio-to-use-more-ram) Didn't work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to make Visual Studio use more memory.  The application itself has no preset limitation.  It will simply use the amount of memory that is granted it by the operating system (just like other apps).

The reason you see it increase to 600MB and then stop is just a side effect of how the managed GC works.  As it performs operations like displaying intellisense, performing edits, etc ... more managed objects will be created.  Eventually the GC is triggered and it reclaims all of the free objects and the longer lived ones are promoted.  Overall though memory usage will be lowered but not as much as before you started editing.  Then you edit some more and this process continues until it reaches the appearance of a steady state.  If you deeply analyze it you'll see that it's actually more of a saw tooth graph of memory usage.

As to why your particular instance of Visual Studio is slow though is hard to determine remotely.  20 projects is a larger solution but performance should still be acceptable even with that many.  Couple of things to try in order to isolate the problem

- Try editing a smaller solution.  It's possible there is one project in particular which is giving VS a problem.  Breaking the project down into smaller solutions could help isolate it.
- Try disabling Aero on your computer. It's possible that WPF is a problem here

Comment: Thank you for the response! About "one project in particular" the best candidate I can think of is a ASP.NET MVC3.0 project and especially RAZOR engine views. I can clearly see the time lag between each character shows up in the markup code as I type. I don't know how to deal with it. I will probably have to downgrade to the traditional MVC view engine. About Aero - it did the trick, I am not sure if it is solely it, but VS works noticeable faster now. Thanks again!

Comment: @bonomo that's a possibility.  Have you tried editting that project in isolation and seeing if the problems repeat?

Comment: just opened that MVC3.0 project alone, the same thing, it's lagging just when I type in a RAZOR view, can clearly see it. Here is one more thing I noticed, the more script elements with links to the outside JavaScript files the slower the view editing becomes. Although it seems obvious that the more JavaScript files referred the more intense load to intellisense etc, but the intellisense cannot resolve the javascript paths (it's dynamic #c expression) and there is no intellisense support for the linked files at all, nevertheless there is a correlation between number of scripts and slowness.

Comment: @bonomo I would definitely report that issue to http://microsoft.connect.com.  It definitely shouldn't be lagging that hard during typing